# Extract group name from one line repeatedly?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, text-processing

I got output from command like below. Need to extract group names.

```
dsAttrTypeNative:memberOf: CN=Grupa_test,OU=Groups,DC=yellow,DC=com CN=Firefox_Install,OU=Groups,DC=yellow,DC=com CN=Network_Admin,OU=Groups,DC=yellow,DC=com
```

So I would like to have something like:

```
Grupa_test
Firefox_Install
Network_Admin
```

Amount of groups will be different each time so I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: Maybe update your question to explain what tools are expected to be used to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' -F'[=,]' 'NR>1{print $2}' file
Grupa_test
Firefox_Install
Network_Admin
```

The above will work with any awk.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '(?<=CN=)[^,]*' file
```

Answer (score 0):

try with following awk too once.

```
awk -v RS='[ ,]' -v FS="=" '/CN=/{print $2}'  Input_file
```

Comment: You should mention that that will only work in GNU awk due to multi-char RS

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v FPAT="CN=[^,]+" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print substr($i,4)}' Input_file
```

Treat every matched `CN=[^,]+` case as a field. And for each matched field, use `substr($i,4)` to filter out `CN=`, to print the desired string.

Comment: I've modified two things and got exactly what I need

'code' dscl /Active\ Directory/YELLOW/All\ Domains read /Users/tzolty dsAttrTypeNative:memberOf | awk -v FPAT="CN=[^,]+" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print substr($i,4)}' | awk -F , '{ print $1}'

so added awk -F , '{ print $1}' because I need only group name and without that it was giving me something like 

Grupa_test,OU=Groups,DC=yellow,DC=com
Firefox_Install,OU=Groups,DC=yellow,DC=com
Network_Admin,OU=Groups,DC=yellow,DC=com

After that change I got below:

Grupa_test
Firefox_Install
Network_Admin

Thanks a lot !!!!

Comment: @Yellow you needed to make that change because the `FPAT` assignment is being ignored and so the first awk script is splitting on spaces by default and so not working for you at all. CWLiu you should mention that your solution requires GNU awk (which the OP apparently is not running).